# Disable print pdf in iframe

Tags: pdf, printing, coldfusion

does anybody know how to disable print/save pdf file? i'm making an application that enable user to view pdf file in an iframe. but i've just been ordered to make it to be as 'viewable but not printable'. now, what i can do is removing the toolbar button, but user still can right click and choose the print option. i had also disabling right click, but id doesn't work in iframe.

Please help.

Comment: Go back to the drawing board. 'Viewable but not printable' is a pipe dream.

Answer (score 3):

When you create the PDF,

- set an admin password
- set an EMPTY user password
- set printing document permission to false

If you do not create the PDFs or cannot edit them, then you cannot make the document view-only.

Comment: This is the correct answer however it does not prevent someone from taking a screenshot, etc

Comment: @VSU: Thanks.okay. the thing is we have a lot of pdf documents. i can't find anything on setting security - disable print by batch processing. it can only works if it's done manually.which is why i hope i can find solution that can disable right click by coding.

those pdf documents are copyright. that's why they want it to be viewable, but not printable..

Antony : i know. but those documents contain hundreds of pages. i don't think they'd want to take screen shot :)

Comment: @dygta - Try the information on http://www.pdfzone.com/c/a/Tips/Using-a-Batch-Tool-to-Change-Security-Setting/ with respect to batch processing.

Comment: Re: *i don't think they'd want to take screen shot*  Never underestimate determined users ;) If someone really wants to find a way around security features .. they usually will.

Comment: Dygta: I have added an update with links to our products that encrypt and set document permissions on PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CFPDF tag to set print permissions. Create copies of all your document and batch process them (or cache them as needed).

```
<cfpdf action="protect" newOwnerPassword="IHaveCoolPasswords" source="cooldocument.pdf" 
    destination="protected_cooldocument.pdf" overwrite="yes" permissions="AllowScreenReaders">
```